# ImportError: cannot import name 'constants'

Tags: python, anaconda, constants, textacy

I need to import the constants library but it is not working...

```
import spacy
import pandas
import textacy
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series
from . import constants
```

Erreur:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-df52595371dd> in <module>()
  4 import pandas as pd
  5 from pandas import Series
----> 6 from . import constants

ImportError: cannot import name 'constants'
```

I am using anaconda 3 on windows 10 and tried to install this library with the conda:

```
conda install -c auto constants
```

But it still does not work...

Comment: why are you doing from . import instead of just import?

Comment: Also not working with import constants... same erreur

Comment: if you type "conda list" into your terminal, is constants there?

Comment: No, it is not there. I had not thought of that ...

Comment: That means your installation failed or you are in a different conda python environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from . import constants
```

imports a python file called constants inside your current directory.

I doubt you installed it in your directory?

so just do `import constants`

. means look in current directory I believe

Answer (score 0):

Using `from` shouldn't be necessary in the last line. Simply type:

```
import constants
```

that should do the trick.